# How to expand box to fill max size and change its zindex when clicked in Jetpack compose with animation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist, android-jetpack-compose-material3

The screen replicates a video call screen.Please see the image.

[image: screenshot].

- There are 2 boxes - green and black.

  - Green box - Remote camera view.
  - Black box is local camera view .

What I need is when clicked local camera view (black box) , it should expand to max size and the green box to take size of black box and bring to front.
The functionality is exactly like a video call screen view switching.
How can i achieve this size and order with a smooth transition .

Answer (score 0):

You can use zIndex to change it:

> Modifier.zIndex(zIndexNumber)

About the animation I think you can use `animateFloatAsState` you can check it here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation

Comment: Not working. Can you please share the code